# Sencha ExtJS 7 - How to handle Blob, File, FormData instance object

Tags: upload, blob, filefield, extjs7

How can i send to server a Blob, File and FormData Instance Object using these two way Ext.Ajax.request and Ext.form.Panel.submit?

```
var blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: chunks[0].type});
var file = new File(["lorem.."], "test.txt", {type: "text/plain"});
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("text", file);
formData.append("video", blob, "video.webm");
```

How to add "formData" or simple "blob" and/or "file" into Ext.Ajax.request(options) and Ext.form.Panel.submit(options)?

Another doubt: How to set "file" into value of "filefield" component?

Thanks!

Comment: In JQuery: $.ajax({... data: formData ....}); How about Sencha ExtJS?

Answer (score 0):

Something in the line of this might work:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({url: 'https://some.url.com', method: 'POST', rawData: formData, contentType: false})
```

You can check out [this thread](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264486-Can-t-use-FormData-with-Ext-Ajax) as well.